# GPO not applying to Clients

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy

I am having issues applying the below GPOs to clients.

```
Computer Configuration \ Policies \ Administrative Templates \ System \ Remote assistance \ "Offer Remote Assistance"

Computer Configuration \ Policies \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Autoplay Policies \ "Turn off Autoplay"
```

These policies are applied against specific containers, but are not applying in both our production environment and our VMWare test lab, even with clean installs.

I have tried with the Firewall and AV disabled on both client and server, without success, and `gpupdate /force` has no effect either. RSOP on the client is seeing the required policy changes but they are not applying for some reason.  I have also added client names to the Security Filtering of that policy and have tried logging on to client with a Domain Admin account, also without success.

At the same time, other policies like "Logon Scripts" and "Encrypting File System" apply fine.

This is from a Windows Server 2008R2 Enterprise server, to Windows 7, SP1 Enterprise clients.

[Here is the link to the output of `/gpresult` on the client](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2YBQ4L4t8Amd1kzZE5aMm5Kams/view?usp=sharing).

RSOP on the client:

[image]

GPMC settings:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is perfectly normal. The Local Group Policy editor is for viewing and configuring the **Local** group policy object and its settings, not for viewing domain based Group Policy settings.

Domain based Group Policies **override** Local Group Policy settings, they do not **overwrite** Local Group Policy settings.

RSOP is the tool for viewing settings that are being applied to the computer and user from domain based Group Policy objects.

Your RSOP results show that the domain based Group Policy settings are in fact being applied to the computer.

Comment: It seems like I need to go back to school to learn how GPO's work. As per your explanation, the GPO is indeed applying to the Client, it is just not reflecting as a change in the Local Policy of the client. Did a quick test with a flash drive with an autorun.inf file and the flash didn't run (which is what I expected), also managed to connect remote assistance to the cleint. Next time I will check and make sure something works instead of assuming it wont because I dont see the expected changes. Anyway, many thanks joeqwerty and HopelessN00b for your assistance, its much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your RSOP screnclip, take a look at the GPO State column.  `Not configured` means it's not configured.  You have to set the state to either `enable` or `disable` for the GPO to actually do anything.  If you `enable` the Remote Assistance GPO, Remote Assistance will be enabled on computers this GPO applies to, and users will be allowed to create Remote Assistance requests from these computers.  If you `disable` the Remote Assistance GPO, Remote Assistance will be disabled on computers this GPO applies to, and users will be **not** allowed to create Remote Assistance requests.

If you take a look at your GPResult output, it tells you why the GPO is not being applied: `Reason denied: Empty`.  IT telling you that your GPO doesn't actually contain any configurations to apply... so they're not being applied.

[image]

So, the reason those GPOs are applying is because they don't do anything. Change the state on those GPO settings from `Not Configured` to the desired state, and they should start working next time your clients fetch group policy.  (And possibly reboot... I don't know off the top of my head if those particular configurations require a reboot or not).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is that the policies are set to enabled in the GPMC (as per the RSOP top snip). This state is however not replicating to the client. You might be onto something with regards to the Local Group Policy, will check it later in the day and report back

Comment: @David That means the ***GPO link*** is enabled. It doesn't mean the settings within it are configured. You need to click into the "Offer Remote Assistance" Setting and change its state to either enabled or disabled.

Comment: please see the following link: http://s27.postimg.org/d9y27l5vn/2015_02_15_013312.png . This is on the Server side, edited from the GPMC, but the state is not replicating to the client. Please advise if you something wrong with my setup

Comment: @David you have enabled the group policy to be deployed to any workstations in that container, however the gpo you have enabled is empty, there's nothing for it to apply to the computer, so the computer has denied that gpo. Also, when you pull up the Local Group Policy editor, that show's you the *local* group policy on the workstation, not the domain policies being applied to the workstation (referring to your top screenshot).